# Can someone explain, in plain English, the difference between ConfigurationSection and ConfigurationElement?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

I'm reading through a fantastic article on the .NET Configuration namespace (found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/CSharpClassFactory.aspx?fid=144617&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=51#xx0xx)) which talks about creating custom sections, elements, collections, widgets, and flying toasters. The only complaint I have is that the article is only technical and doesn't provide any conceptual context. MSDN doesn't appear to have much conceptual information, either.

So can someone explain, please, what a "section" is, what an "element" is, and when it would be appropriate to use each?

Comment: Well I know it's been awhile, and you probably have found an answer, would you please share it if you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better read for you will be this series of articles, which brilliantly tells you about all the details of configurations in C#:

[Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)

[Decoding the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)

[Cracking the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

And to answer your question in simple words, `ConfigurationSection` is a container which contains multiple `ConfigurationElement` and/or `ConfigurationElementCollection`. The parent of `ConfigurationSection` will always be `<configuration>` which is the root element in configuration files.

`ConfigurationElement` is a container and/or single element and is always part of a `ConfigurationSection`.

Comment: :) The link I provided was the first of the three articles that you referenced.

Comment: Oops... "Enter" key sends. I meant to add that "ConfigurationSection" still confuses me. There is a ConfigurationSectionGroup class and ConfigurationSectionCollection class. Also, since a ConfigurationElement can be a container of multiple elements, I still don't understand why there's a different ConfigurationSection class. They seem to be fundamentally the same.